# IPhone Storyboard custom cell disappears when scrolling down

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, ios6

I have just finished a project where I use a custom cell for my TableView in Storyboard.

The problem is that when i scroll down the content in each cell is gone, which in my case is
two Labels.

This is the code I use to present each cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    MessageCell *cell = (MessageCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Message *messageForRow = (Message *)[messages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [cell.messageLabel setText:[messageForRow message]];
    [cell.senderLabel setText:[messageForRow sender]];

    return cell;
}
```

I have specified the right cellidentifier in storyboard and linked the Class to my
custom cell class.

What can be wrong? If there is any needed information I have missed to present, please
tell me.

Best regard
Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself, the problem did not lie within the update method.
By mistake I used the weak signature for the properties in my Message class.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *sender;
```

I solved it by using the strong signature instead.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *sender;
```

This was a great lesson because I didn't fully understand the concept
of strong and weak.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check by logging that this method is called when scrolling?

Comment: The method is called, just checked